# Persist DataContext changes after back button in Win8 Metro app

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I am building a Windows 8 app (C#/XAML) and using the `Frame.Navigate()` property to move between pages. Each page has an AppBar icon that will refresh that data on a page, and set the `DataContext` property. This works, and the UI updates accordingly after the button is pressed.

The problem I'm seeing shows up when I navigate to a different page, then click the back arrow to return to the previous page.

When the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` method runs (after clicking the back arrow), the `e.Parameter` value is and old value (before I clicked the refresh button, and the `DataContext` was updated).

I don't know how to update the parameter value any other way than using `Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageTypeName), paramValue);`, but I don't want to initiate a navigation action.

My question is two fold.

1. How can I persist `DataContext` changes so that when I return to pages, the value I've set is exposed via `e.Parameter` in the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` method.
2. Is there some kind of reference metrial that explains the Navigation lifecycle in Win8 Apps?

... or should I be doing this a different way?

Comment: Why wouldn't you change the data and not the datacontext?

Comment: The data could be entirely different when I rebind. I'm not changing the DataContext so much as binding new data to it.

Comment: The structure of the data isn't changing, just the values themselves. The DataContext represents structure (ie: the model) and its data is the things that change.

Comment: Ok, but I still have no solution to the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` event giving me old data (specifically the `e.Parameter` value set when I ran `Frame.Navigate(typeof(PageTypeName), paramValue)` on the previous page). I need to make sure that when I update the data in DataContext, it's updated there as well, or I'll always have stale data when I press the back button.

Comment: Maybe I should be asking a different question.

Where does the value of `e.Parameter` come from? How do I update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

`NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Required;`

This tells the frame that it should always cache the old instance of my page, and not create a new one when i navigate back to it.

This way my new `DataContext` value is not overwritten when I return to the page.